# Reverse-engineering a weird 32-bit possibly not CRC checksum

Tags: crc, checksum, rf

I am trying to decode Arad/Master Meter utility water meter RF transmission.
So far, I had success with reading the meter serial number and counter reading.
The transmission looks like that:

> ```
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bfa1c907300a80600000506cd192cc8f8
> ```

where:

**00000000** is preamble.

**3e690aec7ac84b** is fixed in time and the same for other meters in the neighborhood. Probably gearing ratio.

**fa1c9073** is Meter serial number. `fa1c90 = 9444602`, little endian `73= 'S'`

**00** no idea.

**a80600** is the counter reading little endian = `1704`

**000** no idea.

**5** is fixed in time and the same for other meters in the neighborhood.

**06cd192cc** probably some kind of CRC or checksum  - **here is where I need help**.

**8** is getting either 8 or 0 same for other meters in the neighborhood.

**f8** is fixed in time and the same for other meters in the neighborhood.

Running:

```
reveng -w 32 -s 3E690AEC7AC84BDAB18C7300390E000005BFF1DB9F
3E690AEC7AC84B13FE8B7300100500000507CBFECD
3E690AEC7AC84BDAB18C73003B0E0000055C91EB1C
3E690AEC7AC84B3EC68C7300720E000005C6E1CCD5
```

I get immediately :

> no models found

So if I am not doing anything wrong, Reveng doesn't seem to find anything with brute force.
Any other idea?

Here is a list of different transmissions I collected:

> ```
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bfa1c907300a206000005483eab4f28f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bfa1c907300a306000005298634f988f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bfa1c907300a4060000056d9fbad9f8f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bfa1c907300a5060000050c27256f58f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bfa1c907300a6060000058eff8a5ae0f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bfa1c907300a706000005ef4715ec40f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bfa1c907300a80600000506cd192cc8f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84b13fe8b73000f050000059576b83160f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84b13fe8b7300100500000507cbfecdb8f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84b3ec68c7300720e000005c6e1ccd5e8f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84b3ec68c7300730e000005a759536348f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84b3ec68c7300750e00000582f842f598f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84b3ec68c7300760e0000050020edc020f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84b3ec68c7300770e0000056198727680f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84b3ec68c7300780e00000588127eb608f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bdab18c7300350e000005d4a3786a70f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bdab18c7300360e000005567bd75fc8f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bdab18c7300380e000005de494429e0f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bdab18c7300390e000005bff1db9f40f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bdab18c73003a0e0000053d2974aaf8f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bdab18c73003b0e0000055c91eb1c58f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bdab18c73003c0e0000051888653c28f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bfa1c907300500600000533712209f0f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bfa1c907300510600000552c9bdbf50f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bfa1c9073005206000005d011128ae8f8
> 000000003e690aec7ac84bfa1c9073005306000005b1a98d3c48f8
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I still cannot directly comment and this is my only option to respond:

[here](https://arad.co.il/app/uploads/Interpreter_Eng.pdf) is description of other parameters from same supplier, maybe same model. Some might be transmitted via RF such as battery status. Meter with 9 digits will consume some of the "0"s. Gives opportunity to improve your protocol description.

> 06cd192cc probably some kind of CRC or checksum - here is where I need help.

You highlighted 9 nibbles. Very unlikely for CRC, for CRC-32 result is 8 nibbles.

> 8 is getting either 8 or 0 same for other meters in the neighborhood

Means that it is unknown at the moment but changes and it is probably in use and included in Checksum. And the same maybe for final "F8".

For your data it is true that

```
0x3e690aec7ac84bfa1c9073005**0**0600000533712209f0f8 ^ 0x3e690aec7ac84bfa1c9073005**1**0600000552c9bdbf50f8 == 0x3e690aec7ac84bfa1c9073005**2**06000005d011128ae8f8 ^ 0x3e690aec7ac84bfa1c9073005**3**06000005b1a98d3c48f8
```

which is true for CRC. So it is not excluding CRC method.

So some options to play with, find right position and length and get a lucky punch with Reveng.

Comment: Could you explain some more as I am new to CRC? Does * in your code line mean wildcard. Does ^ mean power?

Comment: the "wildcards" came from highlighting "0", "1" etc with bold, which looks a bit weird in code. Just to present difference better. "^" is function (at least in Python) for Xor.

Comment: You are correct. My mistake. The counter should be shifted one nibble left. I have corrected that in my original post. Thank you.